# Reduce Mathematica's disk usage

Tags: system-performance

Having had Mathematica installed for a number of years and having upgraded regularly, I find that the disk space used by `.Mathematica` has grown to almost 7 GB.

While not unduly large, I suspect that some of the files stored are now redundant.  What is the best way to identify and remove these in Mathematica 13?

I suspect that old questions on this subject may now be out of date.

Comment: Are you asking about Mathematica installation size? If so, I do not see how this could be an issue these days really. An 8 TB hard disk is now around $130 or so. 8 TB is 8,000 GB. So 7 GB is nothing to worry about. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? How is removing few MB could have any effect on anything?

Comment: @Nasser 7 GB is significant compared with the free space that have on the SSD that I'm using.  Of course, I could symlink it to a location on a different disk partition, but maintaining that is potentially painful, and could cause confusion with my back ups.

Comment: I also use SSD for the boot disk  "C:\" drive on windows (for speed). But all my data is on slower cheaper USB disks.  So this leaves the boot disk only for installation of programs and no user data to preserve space. I do not know if this is what you also do or not. SSD is more expensive, yes.

Comment: Significant portion of Mathematica installation consists of documentation. It is nowadays possible to skip installing it and to use online documentation instead.

Comment: @kirma yes, about 20% of space is docs (on windows at least).   This works until you have no access to the internet (for some reason) and now in the middle of coding something you find you no longer can lookup help on a function you were just about to call :)

Comment: I'm not referring to the total size of the Mathematica install, but to the files cached in my profile (.Mathematica in linux)